# 'require': cannot load such file -- winrm (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have the following script:

```
require_relative 'embedded\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\winrm-1.1.3\winrm.rb'

IP=ARGV[0]
USER=ARGV[1]
endpoint = "http://#{IP}:5985/wsman"
winrm = WinRM::WinRMWebService.new endpoint, :plaintext, user: USER, pass: 'supersecret', basic_auth_only: true
winrm.set_timeout 1800

installer_file = "c:\\Users\\#{USER}\\Downloads\\chef_client.msi"
installer_cmd = "msiexec /qn /i #{installer_file} ADDLOCAL=\"ChefServiceFeature,ChefClientFeature\""

puts 'Installating Chef'
install_output = winrm.cmd installer_cmd

sleep 300
puts 'Configuring Chef'
winrm.cmd %Q(mv c:\\Users\\#{USER}\\Downloads\\client.rb c:\\chef\\client.rb)
winrm.cmd %Q(mv c:\\Users\\#{USER}\\Downloads\\chef-validator.pem c:\\chef\\validation.pem)
winrm.cmd 'net start chef-client || net start chef-client'
```

Whenever I try to run it, I get:  `'require': cannot load such file -- winrm (LoadError)`

I'm using a setup with Ruby193 and Chef, so maybe it has something to do with having 193 and whatever came with Chef on my box? - I can't for the life of me get this to work. I was able to get the winrm gem installed (I think?) but I can't figure out how to access it from my script.

Comment: can't you just `require 'winrm'`? Also, Ruby's `require` takes a path without the `.rb` extension, so you might have luck with `require_relative '...\winrm-1.1.3\winrm'`

Comment: Ruby also uses forward slashes in paths 'embedded/lib/...'. Try changing it too.

Comment: winrm should automatically be loaded by chef. Just require 'chef' on a Windows machine and you'll get WinRM.